# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)$ coverges, does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ also converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)$ coverges and $a_n>0$ for all $n>0$, does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ also converge? I know that the converse of this is true, but would this also be true?

Comment: You know that $a_n\to 0$ and hence $\frac {\log(1+a_n)}{a_n}\to 1$ hence the answer is yes.

Comment: The calculus book I'm using states that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n $ will only converge iff $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \ln(1 + a_n)$ converge for a positive sequence $\{a_n\}$. So It would be interesting to see the converse for comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In spirit, since $\sum_n\ln(1+a_n)$ converges, you have that $a_n\to0$, and then $\ln(1+a_n)\sim a_n$.

Formally, one can show that if $0<x<1$, then $\ln(1+x)\geq x/2$. So, for $k $ big enough,
$$
\sum_{n\geq k}a_n\leq2\,\sum_{n\geq k}\ln(1+a_n)<\infty.
$$

For a proof of the inequality $\ln(1+x)\geq x/2$, note that they agree at $x=0$, and the derivative of the left-hand-side is greater than the derivative of the right-hand-side. Or, one can use the Mean Value Theorem: since $0<x<1$ there exists $c(x)\in(0,1)$ (more properly, $0<c(x)<x$) with 
$$
\ln(1+x)=\ln(1+x)-\ln 1=\frac1{1+c(x)}\,(x-0)\geq\frac x2.
$$

Comment: The argument going through $\ln(1+a_n) \sim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ **is** formal -- this is one of the versions of the comparisons theorems.

Comment: I agree. But it requires the Mean Value Theorem for the estimate, and then the comparison theorem.

Comment: @Martin: If $a_n \sim b_n$ then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge or diverge together, because there exists $N$ such that $|a_n/b_n - 1| < \varepsilon$ for all $n > N$, so $(1-\varepsilon)b_n < a_n < (1+\varepsilon) b_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami I'm working with the same series atm. Could you please explain how you go from $\ln(1+x)\geq x/2\to \sum a_n \leq \frac{1}{2}\sum\ln(1 + a_n)$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you found a typo, my bad. I have edited the answer.